# Using spatial indexes on point to polygon intersection query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-index, st-intersects

I have a table (tab_point) with about 5 million points and another table with a few thousand polygons (tab_polyg). I need to find what points intersect with what polygon (to establish a count of points per polygon). I am really not sure how to use spatial indexes to speed up the query.

I am using this query (it's been running for hours...):

```
SELECT b.POLYG_NAME as POLYG_NAME, count(*) as POINT_COUNT
INTO [result_table]
FROM [tab_point] a WITH (INDEX(tab_point_spa_idx))
JOIN [tab_polyg] b
ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.Shape) = 1
GROUP BY b.POLYG_NAME;
```

As we can see in the query I am using a spatial index for the point table. But I am doing this without much knowledge really.

Generally speaking, if I have a spatial query establishing a relationship between 2 tables, how can I know which one should be using the spatial index?

Should it actually be both?

And also, would it make any difference if I change the order of the STIntersect command? ("ON b.Shape.STIntersects(a.Shape) = 1" instead)

Comment: You might get better performance if you drive the query from the polygon side (a few thousand searches of millions of points should return faster than millions of searches on a few thousand polygons).

Comment: This is for Oracle, not SQL Server, but it still might be helpful. Or maybe you can find a similar article for SQL Server. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010282

Comment: In Oracle, I can look at the Explain Plan to see if a query is using a spatial index or not. I assume the same can be done in SQL Server too. If you're not familiar with explain plans, then I would suggest you read up on them and start using them. Also, once you can see in the Explain Plan that a spatial index is being used, be sure to look up the index name to see what table it belongs to so that you can understand what's happening. Once I got my query using a spatial index properly, the query was orders of magnitude faster. It also might help to simplify polygons (remove unneeded vertices).

Comment: On second thought, I know nothing about SQL Server. When I look at your query again, it looks way different than Oracle. So my comments above might be useless. At any rate, I would suggest doing your testing on a single record or small subset, instead of the whole thing. That would be a lot easier for troubleshooting purposes.